# Disabling shared memory prevents ssh login

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.10

I'm setting up a new Linode server and following steps from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StricterDefaults

2 times now if I follow the following steps:

```
Edit /etc/fstab
Add this line: 
    tmpfs     /dev/shm     tmpfs     defaults,ro     0     0
Reboot
```

After reboot I'm no longer able to ssh into the server.

In /etc/fstab, its indicated in the format comment that the file path should be the first option. "tmpfs" is before that. Could this be a typo in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

First, the syntax as given is correct. The line in `/etc/fstab` is supposed to begin with `tmpfs`. Note that the way you posted it, it begins with spaces, which should *not* be there.

Second, the page you linked to *did* warn you:

> **Note**: MANY programs will **not** work if you make `/dev/shm` read-only (e.g. Google Chrome).

If you're trying to secure `/dev/shm` then that's going too far. Try just `noexec,nosuid` instead.

Comment: True, I did read that. However, it also said that you don't really have to worry about that on server environments, which is what I'm configuring.

Comment: If you really didn't have to worry about it, you would never have run into the problem .. twice.

Comment: Either way, my question is still open. It wasn't about memory, it was about whether the syntax with tmpfs is correct.

Comment: What part of your question remains unanswered?